# How To Customize My Command Line Promt For My Working Directory (Linux)?

Tags: linux, command-line

How would I change this

```
[Sat Jun 02 14:24:12 vivek@server:~ ] $
```

to 
`[Sat Jun 02 14:24:12 vivek@server:myDirectory! ] $`

while "myDirectory!" is customized string that only shows up when I am in my home Directory.
I believe, i'd have to do that in this format `$ PS1="[\d \t \u@\h:\w ] $ "`. I may be wrong.

PS: I don't have linux to fiddle around. I practice in my school.

Answer (score 1):

> Bash provides an environment variable called PROMPT_COMMAND. The contents of this variable are executed as a regular Bash command just before Bash displays a prompt.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html

Insert an if/then statement into PROMPT_COMMAND to change your PS1 variable. Add this line to your .bashrc:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ $PWD == $HOME ]; then PS1="[\d \t \u@\h:myDirectory! ] $ "; else PS1="[\d \t \u@\h:\w ] $ "; fi'
```